# Skip Find Script in Batch if text not found

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, for-loop, find

I have a script that should look through a text file, for its workstation ID and then assign the user next to its Workstation ID to be a local admin.

However, if the computer name is not found, I would like it to simply goto the end of the file, and exit as if it were completed successfully.

I have looked around, but I can't really think of what terms I would use to search for in google.

Any help is much appreciated.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
FIND /i "%computername%" < "C:\Build\Elevate\AccessElevations.txt" >%temp%\computer.txt
FOR /F "tokens=1-6 delims=," %%a in (%temp%\computer.txt) DO (
set school=%%a
set computerid=%%b
set Model=%%c
set Serial=%%d
set user=%%e
set access=%%f
If /i "%%f" EQU "Admin" goto Elevate
If /i "%%f" EQU "NoAdmin" goto End
:Elevate
set desc=!school! - !computerid! - !model! - !serial! - !user!
echo.
echo Now creating local admin account for !user! on !computerid!
echo.
echo Description: !desc!
echo.
net localgroup Administrators "GBN\!user!" /add
net config server /srvcomment:"!desc!"
)

:End
```

Comment: @unclemeat it was failing because it couldn't find the workstation name in the list, but Usr:Magoo had the right idea, thanks for trying to help anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the `FIND /i ...` line

```
if errorlevel 1 goto :eof
```

which goes to the special label `:eof` which `CMD` understands as EndOfFile if the errorlevel established by `find` is non-zero (zero means "found it")